# SSL certificate not accepted

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am quite new to running my own mail server but I feel like I did a good job setting it up. It receives mail fluently but sending mail causes some issues.

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
SSL_accept error from 5354D677.cm-6-5d.dynamic.ziggo.nl
```

And:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.challenge-all.com:587 -debug
result: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:749
```

Thunderbird mail client (on send mail) (translated freely from dutch to english):

```
Sending of the message failed. Message can not be sent via
SMTP-server smtp.challenge-all.com for an unknown reason.
```

I would be quite willing to supply more information, if you guys would be so kind to assist this eager but green mail server owner/maintainer :-)

Additional info edit:

- I am using a setup of postfix/dovecot with spamassassin and clamav
- I got my signed certs from startssl.com and https://www.startssl.com/ did chain with their intermediate CA

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:587` is producing expected results because the protocol starts out in plain text, and switches to TLS with `STARTTLS` extension. You would get the same result with `openssl s_client -connect www.mydomain.com:80`. Take a look at the docs on `s_client` to see how to work with mail protocols.

Comment: When I run `s_client`, I get `connect: Connection refused`. Are you sure you have a mail server at `mail.mydomain.com` listening on port 587?

Comment: "I got my signed certs from startssl.com and did chain with their root CA". Your end-entity (server) certificate should have *two* certs in it. First is your servers certificate, and second is Startcom's Class 1 Server Intermediate. You can get the Class 1 Intermediate at [Index of Certs](https://www.startssl.com/certs/). The client (whomever that is) will need to trust Startcom's Root CA. For OpenSSL's `s_client`, that means you need to add `-CAfile startcom-ca.pem`.

Comment: "When I run s_client, I get connect: Connection refused. Are you sure you have a mail server at mail.mydomain.com listening on port 587?"
I've updated my info to show my actual domain name (which is challenge-all.com
Also I did infact chain with the intermediate certificate from startssl, that was my bad!

Comment: **openssl s_client -connect challenge-all.com:587 -showcerts -CAfile /etc/test/startcom-ca.pem resulted in:**
`CONNECTED(00000003)
140277689325216:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:749:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 225 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
`

the certificate I used in the openssl test is the root certificate from startcom

Comment: Port 587 is for Mail Submission Agents (MSA). Its essentially SMTP that allows roaming users to contact their "home" MTA. MSA uses `STARTTLS` to enable TLS, just like SMTP. I believe your `s_client` command needs to include `-starttls smtp`. See the docs for [`s_client`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).

Comment: You should probably move this to Super User or Server Fault. You'll probably find more administrators on those sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Sending of the message failed. Message can not be sent via
> SMTP-server smtp.challenge-all.com for an unknown reason.
> ```

According to `nslookup` (below), your mail server is `mail.challenge-all.com`, not `smtp.challenge-all.com`.

---

> ```
> openssl s_client -connect mail.challenge-all.com:587 -debug
> result: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:749
> ```

Here's what I am seeing (below). The chain verifies OK when using `ca-pem` from [Index of Certs](https://www.startssl.com/certs/), dated 07-May-2008 03:49.

It looks like you are using Client Certificates. I've never configured mail to use client certs, so I probably cannot help any further.

I'm also suspicious that you would trust all certificates from the CA Zoo (rather than just your organization's PKI). That might be a configuration issue. Is this a Microsoft server? Didn't Microsoft servers start sending them due to a recent patch? See [SSL/TLS communication problems after you install KB 931125](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801679/en-us).

Finally, TÜRKTRUST (CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika...) should probably *not* be trusted. They (or one of the subs) were caught issuing certificates for domains like `google.com`. See [Deal with TURKTRUST mis-issued certificates](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825022). I think they were also certifying public keys that were too small (like 512-bits).

---

```
$ nslookup
> set q=MX
> challenge-all.com
Server:     172.16.1.10
Address:    172.16.1.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
challenge-all.com   mail exchanger = 10 mail.challenge-all.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
mail.challenge-all.com  internet address = 128.204.195.123

$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect mail.challenge-all.com:587 -CAfile startcom-ca.pem -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = NL, CN = mail.challenge-all.com, emailAddress = djvanderburgt@gmail.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=NL/CN=mail.challenge-all.com/emailAddress=djvanderburgt@gmail.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=NL/CN=mail.challenge-all.com/emailAddress=djvanderburgt@gmail.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=AT/O=A-Trust Ges. f. Sicherheitssysteme im elektr. Datenverkehr GmbH/OU=A-Trust-nQual-03/CN=A-Trust-nQual-03
/CN=ACEDICOM Root/OU=PKI/O=EDICOM/C=ES
/C=CO/O=Sociedad Cameral de Certificaci\xC3\xB3n Digital - Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A./CN=AC Ra\xC3\xADz Certic\xC3\xA1mara S.A.
/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust TTP Network/CN=AddTrust Class 1 CA Root
/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust TTP Network/CN=AddTrust Public CA Root
/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust TTP Network/CN=AddTrust Qualified CA Root
/C=US/O=AffirmTrust/CN=AffirmTrust Commercial
/C=US/O=AffirmTrust/CN=AffirmTrust Networking
/C=US/O=AffirmTrust/CN=AffirmTrust Premium
/C=US/O=AffirmTrust/CN=AffirmTrust Premium ECC
/C=US/O=America Online Inc./CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1
/C=US/O=America Online Inc./CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 2
/C=JP/O=Japanese Government/OU=ApplicationCA
/C=ES/CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068
/C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
/C=NO/O=Buypass AS-983163327/CN=Buypass Class 2 CA 1
/C=NO/O=Buypass AS-983163327/CN=Buypass Class 3 CA 1
/C=SK/L=Bratislava/O=Disig a.s./CN=CA Disig
/C=CN/O=CNNIC/CN=CNNIC ROOT
/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO Certification Authority
/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority
/C=EU/O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287/OU=http://www.chambersign.org/CN=Chambers of Commerce Root
/C=EU/O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287/OU=http://www.chambersign.org/CN=Global Chambersign Root
/C=FR/O=Dhimyotis/CN=Certigna
/C=FR/O=Certinomis/OU=0002 433998903/CN=Certinomis - Autorit\xC3\xA9 Racine
/C=FR/O=Certplus/CN=Class 2 Primary CA
/C=PL/O=Unizeto Sp. z o.o./CN=Certum CA
/C=PL/O=Unizeto Technologies S.A./OU=Certum Certification Authority/CN=Certum Trusted Network CA
/C=EU/L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address)/serialNumber=A82743287/O=AC Camerfirma S.A./CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008
/CN=ComSign CA/O=ComSign/C=IL
/CN=ComSign Secured CA/O=ComSign/C=IL
/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services
/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=Secure Certificate Services
/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=Trusted Certificate Services
/O=Cybertrust, Inc/CN=Cybertrust Global Root
/C=US/O=Digital Signature Trust/OU=DST ACES/CN=DST ACES CA X6
/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
/C=DE/O=Deutsche Telekom AG/OU=T-TeleSec Trust Center/CN=Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2
/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
/C=US/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./OU=DSTCA E1
/C=US/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./OU=DSTCA E2
/C=TR/O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S./CN=e-Guven Kok Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Saglayicisi
/CN=EBG Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/O=EBG Bili\xC5\x9Fim Teknolojileri ve Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E./C=TR
/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
/C=US/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
/C=US/O=Equifax Secure Inc./CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1
/C=US/O=Equifax Secure Inc./CN=Equifax Secure eBusiness CA-1
/C=ES/L=C/ Muntaner 244 Barcelona/CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068/emailAddress=ca@firmaprofesional.com
/C=US/O=GTE Corporation/OU=GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc./CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA 2
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Universal CA
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Universal CA 2
/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
/C=EU/L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address)/serialNumber=A82743287/O=AC Camerfirma S.A./CN=Global Chambersign Root - 2008
/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
/C=HK/O=Hongkong Post/CN=Hongkong Post Root CA 1
/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=PM/SGDN/OU=DCSSI/CN=IGC/A/emailAddress=igca@sgdn.pm.gouv.fr
/C=ES/O=IZENPE S.A./CN=Izenpe.com
/emailAddress=pki@sk.ee/C=EE/O=AS Sertifitseerimiskeskus/CN=Juur-SK
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=Microsec Ltd./OU=e-Szigno CA/CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=Microsec Ltd./CN=Microsec e-Szigno Root CA 2009/emailAddress=info@e-szigno.hu
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=NetLock Kft./OU=Tan\xC3\xBAs\xC3\xADtv\xC3\xA1nykiad\xC3\xB3k (Certification Services)/CN=NetLock Arany (Class Gold) F\xC5\x91tan\xC3\xBAs\xC3\xADtv\xC3\xA1ny
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=NetLock Halozatbiztonsagi Kft./OU=Tanusitvanykiadok/CN=NetLock Uzleti (Class B) Tanusitvanykiado
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=NetLock Halozatbiztonsagi Kft./OU=Tanusitvanykiadok/CN=NetLock Expressz (Class C) Tanusitvanykiado
/C=HU/ST=Hungary/L=Budapest/O=NetLock Halozatbiztonsagi Kft./OU=Tanusitvanykiadok/CN=NetLock Kozjegyzoi (Class A) Tanusitvanykiado
/C=HU/L=Budapest/O=NetLock Halozatbiztonsagi Kft./OU=Tanusitvanykiadok/CN=NetLock Minositett Kozjegyzoi (Class QA) Tanusitvanykiado/emailAddress=info@netlock.hu
/C=US/O=Network Solutions L.L.C./CN=Network Solutions Certificate Authority
/C=CH/O=WISeKey/OU=Copyright (c) 2005/OU=OISTE Foundation Endorsed/CN=OISTE WISeKey Global Root GA CA
/C=BM/O=QuoVadis Limited/OU=Root Certification Authority/CN=QuoVadis Root Certification Authority
/C=BM/O=QuoVadis Limited/CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2
/C=BM/O=QuoVadis Limited/CN=QuoVadis Root CA 3
/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 3 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
/O=RSA Security Inc/OU=RSA Security 2048 V3
/C=ES/O=Generalitat Valenciana/OU=PKIGVA/CN=Root CA Generalitat Valenciana
/C=DE/ST=Baden-Wuerttemberg (BW)/L=Stuttgart/O=Deutscher Sparkassen Verlag GmbH/CN=S-TRUST Authentication and Encryption Root CA 2005:PN
/C=JP/O=Japan Certification Services, Inc./CN=SecureSign RootCA11
/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=Secure Global CA
/C=JP/O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD./OU=Security Communication EV RootCA1
/C=JP/O=SECOM Trust.net/OU=Security Communication RootCA1
/C=FI/O=Sonera/CN=Sonera Class1 CA
/C=FI/O=Sonera/CN=Sonera Class2 CA
/C=NL/O=Staat der Nederlanden/CN=Staat der Nederlanden Root CA
/C=NL/O=Staat der Nederlanden/CN=Staat der Nederlanden Root CA - G2
/C=US/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2
/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=Starfield Technologies, Inc./CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
/C=CH/O=SwissSign AG/CN=SwissSign Gold CA - G2
/C=CH/O=SwissSign AG/CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2
/C=CH/O=SwissSign AG/CN=SwissSign Silver CA - G2
/C=ch/O=Swisscom/OU=Digital Certificate Services/CN=Swisscom Root CA 1
/C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II
/C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA II
/C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Universal CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Universal CA I
/C=DK/O=TDC Internet/OU=TDC Internet Root CA
/C=DK/O=TDC/CN=TDC OCES CA
/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/C=TR/L=ANKARA/O=(c) 2005 T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E.
/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/C=TR/L=Ankara/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Kas\xC4\xB1m 2005
/C=TW/O=TAIWAN-CA/OU=Root CA/CN=TWCA Root Certification Authority
/C=TW/O=Government Root Certification Authority
/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Premium Server CA/emailAddress=premium-server@thawte.com
/C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Cape Town/O=Thawte Consulting cc/OU=Certification Services Division/CN=Thawte Server CA/emailAddress=server-certs@thawte.com
/C=TR/L=Gebze - Kocaeli/O=T\xC3\xBCrkiye Bilimsel ve Teknolojik Ara\xC5\x9Ft\xC4\xB1rma Kurumu - T\xC3\x9CB\xC4\xB0TAK/OU=Ulusal Elektronik ve Kriptoloji Ara\xC5\x9Ft\xC4\xB1rma Enstit\xC3\xBCs\xC3\xBC - UEKAE/OU=Kamu Sertifikasyon Merkezi/CN=T\xC3\x9CB\xC4\xB0TAK UEKAE K\xC3\xB6k Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1 - S\xC3\xBCr\xC3\xBCm 3
/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN - DATACorp SGC
/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email
/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 1 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2007 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G4
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VISA/OU=Visa International Service Association/CN=Visa eCommerce Root
/C=US/O=Wells Fargo WellsSecure/OU=Wells Fargo Bank NA/CN=WellsSecure Public Root Certificate Authority
/C=US/O=Wells Fargo/OU=Wells Fargo Certification Authority/CN=Wells Fargo Root Certificate Authority
/C=US/OU=www.xrampsecurity.com/O=XRamp Security Services Inc/CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority
/C=RO/O=certSIGN/OU=certSIGN ROOT CA
/C=TW/O=Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd./OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority
/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA
/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=(c) 2007 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G2
/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2008 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3
/C=US/ST=Indiana/L=Indianapolis/O=Software in the Public Interest/OU=hostmaster/CN=Certificate Authority/emailAddress=hostmaster@spi-inc.org
/C=IT/L=Milan/O=Actalis S.p.A./03358520967/CN=Actalis Authentication Root CA
/C=NO/O=Buypass AS-983163327/CN=Buypass Class 2 Root CA
/C=NO/O=Buypass AS-983163327/CN=Buypass Class 3 Root CA
/C=SK/L=Bratislava/O=Disig a.s./CN=CA Disig Root R1
/C=SK/L=Bratislava/O=Disig a.s./CN=CA Disig Root R2
/C=CN/O=China Internet Network Information Center/CN=China Internet Network Information Center EV Certificates Root
/C=DE/O=D-Trust GmbH/CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 2009
/C=DE/O=D-Trust GmbH/CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 EV 2009
/C=ES/O=Agencia Catalana de Certificacio (NIF Q-0801176-I)/OU=Serveis Publics de Certificacio/OU=Vegeu https://www.catcert.net/verarrel (c)03/OU=Jerarquia Entitats de Certificacio Catalanes/CN=EC-ACC
/C=EE/O=AS Sertifitseerimiskeskus/CN=EE Certification Centre Root CA/emailAddress=pki@sk.ee
/C=GR/O=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions Cert. Authority/CN=Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions RootCA 2011
/emailAddress=contacto@procert.net.ve/L=Chacao/ST=Miranda/OU=Proveedor de Certificados PROCERT/O=Sistema Nacional de Certificacion Electronica/C=VE/CN=PSCProcert
/C=JP/O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD./OU=Security Communication RootCA2
/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./CN=StartCom Certification Authority G2
/C=ch/O=Swisscom/OU=Digital Certificate Services/CN=Swisscom Root CA 2
/C=ch/O=Swisscom/OU=Digital Certificate Services/CN=Swisscom Root EV CA 2
/C=GB/O=Trustis Limited/OU=Trustis FPS Root CA
/C=DE/O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH/OU=T-Systems Trust Center/CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3
/CN=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sa\xC4\x9Flay\xC4\xB1c\xC4\xB1s\xC4\xB1/C=TR/L=Ankara/O=T\xC3\x9CRKTRUST Bilgi \xC4\xB0leti\xC5\x9Fim ve Bili\xC5\x9Fim G\xC3\xBCvenli\xC4\x9Fi Hizmetleri A.\xC5\x9E. (c) Aral\xC4\xB1k 2007
---
SSL handshake has read 24299 bytes and written 690 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A7E1172CFFA1062B7B63C09F59ED67D457609FABD002E4973503E32ACDAD0561
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: AC02EFCACCF44A4ED343F99B23D049B177C2046051B16901CB7DC74A72D6C88B6286E17DC5CDDD7A949B5B38D43EEFF3
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 3600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - d6 3f 77 72 67 25 71 e5-18 3a 60 d2 3f 80 f3 7b   .?wrg%q..:`.?..{
    0010 - 97 76 d7 ad b8 5f 10 b0-2e 8b ca 60 b3 b1 a6 24   .v..._.....`...$
    0020 - 80 66 77 0a 13 c1 87 67-b4 ba d6 e6 17 99 76 3c   .fw....g......v<
    0030 - a2 d1 5b e5 93 2c 99 43-2b d2 fb ae 0d 51 13 4c   ..[..,.C+....Q.L
    0040 - 83 2a 13 e3 f6 56 b4 28-74 12 05 2a 6a 61 cc 51   .*...V.(t..*ja.Q
    0050 - 29 7f a5 c2 d5 a9 63 e6-62 bd 42 2d ed 5c 36 df   ).....c.b.B-.\6.
    0060 - eb c8 10 c5 f7 ea 48 04-a9 e2 4c 49 3c 7b 92 56   ......H...LI<{.V
    0070 - 77 bc 72 6f e0 d4 85 11-dd 8b d5 35 e8 82 6e 9f   w.ro.......5..n.
    0080 - 0d a9 74 a5 ea 70 a8 e7-8e a0 0b 2a 8d f6 4f 22   ..t..p.....*..O"
    0090 - 1d 92 f0 ad 73 13 d0 4c-85 be 5b 5a 60 28 e5 ce   ....s..L..[Z`(..

    Start Time: 1398160360
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback! 
I made a cname record for the smtp part: `smtp
is an alias of challenge-all.com`
so that should still work right? challenge-all.com is also an A record so :)
The server itself is a linux server (ubuntu to be exact), I read about using a CA folder that comes with the installation I am using, I guess I should revisit that choice, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It appears the `CNAME` is not working. Mail User Agents (MUAs) like Thunderbird use `MX` records.

Comment: Ah I have one MX record setup, Ill setup one specifically for smtp.challenge-all.com thanks!

I have set my thunderbird to use mail.challenge-all.com now for testing purposes the result is indeed a different one, though not very satisfying yet. (translated from dutch):

The mailserver anwered: 5.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [87.213.98.98]. Check the mail receiver djvanderburgt@gmail.com and try again.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. You should probably move this to Super User or Server Fault. That's where I ask my mail and Postfix/Dovecot/SpamAssassin/Clam questions.

Comment: Sounds like sound advice, thanks for the time!